# Get CSRF error when trying to delete one model from another in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

So in the index for one model, I have a list of associated models. In the list I include the delete postlink.

However, it seems that using the delete postlink to delete one model when in a view belonging to another throws a CSRF error.

This might just be the way Cake's Security component works, but is there any way around this (without compromising the security measures)?

Edit: Adding code.

Post link in a view (in this case, the index view for my Exercise model):

```
echo $this->Form->postLink('Delete', array('controller' => 'folders', 'action' => 'delete', $key), array('class' => 'delete', 'confirm' => 'Are you sure? This will also delete all associated exercises.'));
```

The Delete action in the Folder controller:

```
public function delete($id) {
    if ($this->request->is('get')) {
        throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
    }
    if ($this->Folder->delete()) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Folder '.$id.' has been deleted.', 'default', array('class' => 'success'));
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'exercises', 'action' => 'index'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code of the delete post link or how you're displaying the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CakePHP Security Component allows you to specify which Controllers and/or actions are allowed to send requests to your action.

Read this part of the documentation [Restricting cross controller communication](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#restricting-cross-controller-communication)

Comment: I knew there had to be something along those lines. I'd thought adding  `'authorize' => array('Controller')` to the Auth Component would handle that but I guess not! Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help! No hacks were harmed during the implementation of this setting :)

Comment: What did you do exactly? I followed the link but didn't get how to implement it.